# AS3, how to trigger a search function when item is selected in combobox?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, function, combobox, selecteditem

I have a combobox that act as autosuggestion for a search application. Search function is getting triggered by a search button. I also want to trigger the search function either when the item in combobox is double or single clicked. Code:

```
 //for triggering search function from combobox(search_complex) it will be   
   something like that but i am not sure 
   search_complex.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, search);
   search(event:Event):void{//something will come hereto use "selctedItem" to
   trigger search function}


 //search function which is working fine by pressing search button
 bt_search.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, search);
 function search(MouseEvent):void{
 currentUserbase = [];
 for (var n:int = 0; n<allUserbase.length; n++)
 { 
 for (var k:int = 0; k<allUserbase[n].complex.length; k++)
 {
 if ((allUserbase[n].complex[k].value.toLowerCase() == 
 search_complex.text.toLowerCase() || search_complex.text==""))
 {   
 currentUserbase.push(allUserbase[n]);
 }
 }
 }
 updateList();
 }//end search
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're on the right track. Try:

```
search_complex.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, search);
bt_search.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, search);

function search(event:Event):void
{
  currentUserbase = [];
  for (var n:int = 0; n<allUserbase.length; n++)
  { 
    for (var k:int = 0; k<allUserbase[n].complex.length; k++)
    {
      if ((allUserbase[n].complex[k].value.toLowerCase() ==  search_complex.text.toLowerCase() || search_complex.text==""))
      {   
        currentUserbase.push(allUserbase[n]);
      }
    }
  }

  updateList();

}//end search
```

You should be able to get the selected item in your combobox using `search_complex.selectedItem.label` or `search_complex.selectedItem.label` depending on which property you need to use.

Comment: @jason, thanks for replying, but where and how do i use search_complex.selectedItem.label and how so that when i select a item in combobox it will trigger "search" function

Comment: @hanna, Assuming `search` is the function that's actually performing the search it will automatically get called whenever the `bt_search` button is clicked or when an item is selected from the `search_complex combobox`. That's what the eventListeners are for at the top of my example. As for when to use the `search_complex.selectedItem.label`, I'm assuming you would use it wherever you needed to set your search criteria. If `updateList()` is performing the search using the contents of the `currentUserbase` array, you would add `search_complex.selectedItem.label` to the array in `search()`.

Comment: @jason, thanks for helping me out here, but i am still confused about things, I am actualy using autocomple box from AutoComplete Advanced Example in the follwing Link: http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/autocomplete/examples.html  Now when i use search_complex.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, search); it only performs the search on the first item of the dropdownlist automatically and not on the item user selects. updateList is just updating a another list with results when the search function is completed.

Comment: @hanna, Looking at that example it looks like the user can either click an item in that dropdown or they could press enter to perform the search. Instead of using `Event.CHANGE`, try using `MouseEvent.CLICK` as your even listener. You'll have to add a check in your eventListener to see if there's a selectedItem or not and if the target of the click was the dropdown list of the AutoCompleteBox. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @hanna, Hmmm. What if you went back to `Event.CHANGE` but instead of using the selectedItem, you use the contents of the textbox? You would have to set the `autoFillEnabled` property to true for this to potentially work.

Comment: You could also try adding an eventListener for `Event.CLOSE`. Found on this post: http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=808529 and in the Yahoo documentation: http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/classreference/.

Comment: @Jason Towne, thanks a lott!!! for the help. Event.Close worked perfectly fine... thank you soooo much.. you are a lifesaver!!

Comment: @Jason, the only problem i am having now is that when i backspace all the characters in the search_complex textfield, the display grid gets automatically filled by all results in allUserbase array, and that too twice..:(

Comment: @hanna, Try doing a check to see if the contents of the `TextField` are empty before performing the search. That should prevent the entire contents of the allUserbase array getting added. By the way, if my answer helped you solve your problem, marking it as the answer and adding an upvote is appreciated. It lets others know which answer can help solve their issue if they have a similar problem and it lets the people who help out know their work is appreciated. :)

Comment: @ Jason towne, I got this too, my bad, my search function was: if ((allUserbase[n].complex[k].value.toLowerCase() == search_complex.text.toLowerCase()|| search_complex.text=="")), so have to take out /*|| search_complex.text==""*/..and it worked.. :).. really thanks a lot for all your help.. will do what you said..for the answer and vote..

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you exactly want.

Is it rue that you have a search function, that will work fine.
Now you don't need for each event seperate handler. It is enough to use one for all events. As functionparameter use type "Event" because all other events inherit from this base class.

Check my Code. cd is my combobox. This example is written in flex3

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        [Bindable] private var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {name:"Alexander"},
            {name:"Bernd"},
            {name:"Carl"}
        ]);

        private function init():void
        {
            cb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,search);
            cb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,search);
            cb.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,search);
        }

        private function search (event:Event) :void
        {
            trace (event.type);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```